# DLink Switch OID for community string

Tags: linux, bash, switch-statement, snmp

What would be the OID for this table as given below for DES-3528 DLink Switch

`DES-3528:admin#show snmp comm`
`Command: show snmp community`

`SNMP Community Table`
`Community Name                    View Name                         Access Right`
`--------------------------------  --------------------------------  -----------`
`private                           CommunityView                     read_write`
`public                            CommunityView                     read_only`

`Total Entries: 2`

I need to read the table value `private` for Access Right `read_write`
using "snmpwalk or snmpget", please let me know if anyone know the oid for the same

Answer (score 1):

That would be snmpCommunityTable OID 1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.1 in SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB defined in [RFC 3584](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3584)

Comment: I used this oid but getting response as given below  
`user@device:~# snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.xx.x 1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.1`  

`SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB::snmpCommunityTable = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

Comment: I have used `SNMPv2-MIB`, `SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB` and `SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB` mib file to read the same snmp table from the given link [https://iphostmonitor.com/mib/indexs.html](https://iphostmonitor.com/mib/indexs.html) but i did not get any string `public` or `private` in output i used the snmp command :-  

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public -On -m <mibfile> 192.168.xxx.x`

Comment: Either the MIB is not supported ( you need to check the manual, or with their technical support or forum), or it is protected. Likely the latter. I would not open up the passwords to the public view.